# MailMessage throws a Configuration Exception

Tags: c#, exception, configuration, mailmessage

I don't understand what needs to be added to the config file or anywhere else. The tutorials don't show anything else and I can't find an answer. Please help.
I removed all other code and just left this part since this was the problem. 
Here is the code:

```
using CommandLine; 
using CommandLine.Text; 
using System; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Net.Mail; 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SendMail {
    public class SendMail
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //code that executes just fine and has nothing to do with the MailMessage.
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            //unreachable code that can't be at fault because it doesn't reach here.
        }
    }
```

And this is the App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <add key="COMPANYEMAIL" value="*******************" />
  <add key="COMPANYEMAILPASSWORD" value="*******" />
</configuration>
```

This info is used later in code so it can't be the problem because it doesn't reach the point where I call it. It passes the first part of the code just fine and then when trying to execute that line it breaks. Someone please help me.

[image: errorMessage]

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [mailsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/mailsettings-element-network-settings) configuration element

```
<configuration>  
  <system.net>  
    <mailSettings>  
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">  
        <network  
          host="localhost"  
          port="25"  
          defaultCredentials="true"  
        />  
      </smtp>  
    </mailSettings>  
  </system.net>  
</configuration>
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) there is an expample on how to send a message

Comment: I did. And it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I needed to wrap my `<add>` elements in `<appSettings>` element